Inequality between inverses of real functions
Let $s\geq 0$ and
$$
f(x)=-\log(x) \quad\text{an}\quad g(x)= \log(\log(1/x)+1)$$ for all $x\in(0,1)$. Is there exists $C_s>0$ such that for all $x,y\in(0,1)$,
$$
 f^{-1}(s g(x)) \cdot f^{-1}(s g(y)) \leq f^{-1}(s g(x y))
\leq C_s \cdot f^{-1}(s g(x)) \cdot
f^{-1}(s g(y))?
$$
